# MYSQL calcular a porcentagem escolhida

Tags: mysql, porcentagem

Estou fazendo um QUIZ e em um certo momento tenho que mostrar a porcentagem das alternativas escolhidas pelos usuários. Tenho essa tabela:

```
ID RESPOSTA
1  a
2  a
3  b
4  b
5  c
6  a
```

A resposta que preciso ter do MYSQL seria as porcentagens de escolha:

a - 50%
b - 33,33%
c - 16,6%

Como fazer isso? Tentei com GROUP BY, mas não rolou, alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

não sei se seria a melhor forma de fazer isso, mas eu faria assim:

```
SELECT count(q.id) / t.total * 100 as perc, resposta from quiz q,
( SELECT count(*) as total from quiz ) t
GROUP BY q.resposta
```

Comment: Oi, deu certinho. Mas quando coloco um WHERE, para escolher só a alternativa escolhida de uma pergunta da erro:

$sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(q.id) / t.total * 100 as perc, q.resposta FROM quiz_resposta q,
  (SELECT count(*) as total FROM quiz_resposta) t
  GROUP BY q.resposta
  WHERE q.idpergunta = :pergunta');

Comment: where vem antes de group by

Comment: exato, o where deve ser inserido antes do group by

Comment: No subselect total também deve ter o where, senão trará o total de todas as perguntas, creio que ficaria mais ou menos assim: $sql = $pdo->prepare('SELEC‌​T count(q.id) / t.total * 100 as perc, q.resposta FROM quiz_resposta q, (SELECT count(*) as total FROM quiz_resposta WHERE idpergunta = :pergunta) t WHERE q.idpergunta = :pergunta GROUP BY q.resposta');

Comment: Valeu, certinho e ta bem rápida a consulta.